# XML de tabela MySQL via Access

Tags: mysql, web-service, xml, microsoft-access

Preciso primeiramente saber se o Access consegue conectar a banco MySQL.

A partir dessa conexão, preciso gerar através do Access um XML que contenha os dados de uma tabela do meu banco MySQL. Posteriormente esse XML deverá ser enviado para um servidor remoto todo dia (por Webservice provavelmente).

Alguém sabe se é possível?

Comment: É possível acessar base de dados mysql pelo access udando ODBC: http://www.usandoaccess.com.br/tutoriais/configurar-access-com-mysql-via-odbc.asp?id=1. Não vou postar como resposta porque não testei. Mas foi a primeira resposta do Google.

Comment: @CelsoMarigoJr Vou dar uma olhada. A parte de geração do XML pelo Access tu sabe de algum link na internet que explique como fazer?